# Optional Nested relationships in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a serializer/view that accepts these both jsons:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "foobar": "bazz",
    "info": [
        {
            "field": "value",
            "field2": "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

and

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "foobar": "bazz",
}
```

Where the "info" node is optional.

Right now I tried:

1. Defining the nested relation as "required=False"
2. Extending the simpler serializer.

Both solutions didn't work. That meaning that default "is_valid()" doesn't work for both jsons.

There's any way of doing so in a DRY way?

#### Edit, adding some code:

I'm extending APIView for the view, and serializers.Serializer for the Serializer, there's just not much code available to show.

```
class InfoSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    field = serializer.CharField()
    field2 = serializer.Charfield()

class FooBarSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    foo = serializer.CharField()
    foobar = serializer.CharField()
    info = InfoSerializer(many=True, required=False)
```

and for the view:

```
class FooBarView(APIView):
    
     def post(self, request, format=None):
         data = FooBarSerializer(request.DATA)
         if data.is_valid():
             return Response("{'response': 'valid'}")
         return Response("{'response': 'invalid'}")
```

Comment: What type of serializer and view do you use? Give us the code that you've tried to work with..

Comment: @mariodev there's really not much code yet, that's basically what I've put earlier, i'm trying to decide how to do that and keep adding logic later.

Comment: Just can tell, when setting required=False on a ModelSerializers it works just as desired (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects).

Comment: @Kim thanks for the info, I sincerely don't remember my use-case anymore for this questions, DRF has changed a lot in the last three years and it's nice to know that it's working as expected now, thanks :)

Comment: @DaneoShiga Kudos go to you, as your post actually helped me to deal with exactly the same problem. Just added the info for anyone who pops on this thread like I did :-)